# Spark execution gives "Invalid Log directory error"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am newbie on spark and was trying to execute my jar on the cluster. while i run the jar, the job fails with error Error: invalid log directory /usr/share/spark-2.1.1/work//7/
In another thread where it was suggested to remove flag : SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true". I also changed the permission of the log directory on all the workers.
 Nothing helped. can someone help me understanding why it fails.

Comment: Did you find the root cause for this issue? I am having the same problem in Spark 2.1

Comment: Were you able to sort it out @RossBrigoli

Comment: I remember the reason but i don't exactly remember how i fixed it. The reason was that the work folder is getting deleted. If i remember correctly, the log directory was an nfs mounted path that is common among the worker nodes. When one of the worker jvm process finishes all the task, it cleaned up the work directory, causing the other JVMs on the other nodes to fail with the above error.